# Is this over sensitivity, driver, or hardware issue

Tags: mouse, lenovo-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

I can't figure out what kind of problem this is. Here is the scenario:

> Suddenly, the Synoptics touchpad on a Lenovo Yoga 13 started to behave
>   strangely. The most strange thing is when the computer is put on an
>   external fan which causes the mouse pointer on the screen to go up and down (randomly) when the finger presses constantly on one point.

I tried to investigate this by looking at the information that the touch pad receives before and after a fan is turned on. The pressure graph is shown below:

[image]

The area in the beginning is when the fan (external) is turned off, while the rest is when it is turned on.

I have also reinstalled the driver, installed the old driver, and even when the driver is uninstalled, this continues. In addition, I have observed this error to continue in the login screen too. The reason why it might be a driver/windows update error is because the external fan and the touch pad worked perfectly for almost a year and also that now the mouse is even faster than before. However, because this happens in safe mode too, I suspect it can be a hardware error.

Does anyone have any ideas what can be the cause for this and how this can be fixed?

I am using Windows 8.1 (64bit)

In the device settings: it says that it works properly.

Edit: the fan is an external USB fan, but instead of connecting it to the computer using USB, it is connected to an external power source (adapter).
Also, I have noticed that the mouse is oversensetive, that is, it is much faster and feels everything.

Comment: Can you give more information about the external fan? Is it part of the laptop (integrated) or a usb powered fan that you can move around? Is there other hardware that affects the touchpad?

Comment: Device settings in `devmgmt.msc` will always say it works properly unless there's a driver loading, discovery, or initialization issue.  It's a badly worded message in the device manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be having the same problem: when I charge my laptop, I can feel a little electric current. That's caused by a little current through over casing of the machine. Then my Touch pad is more sensitive indeed. In combination with the new fan, this can be the problem. So two short questions: is the extra sensitivity also there when working on battery? If not so: that's a common feature of some laptops. And next: what kind of casing does your laptop have?

Comment: First q: I will try this out, but since my battery is only charged up to 60%, I don't see any diff. in sensitivity when on battery or without(I will have to experiment with fan or of and I will tell you). Second q: it is some sort of metal.

Comment: I think that once the fan is connected to PC as a source, everything seems to work fine. I have also decreased mouse speed in options.

Comment: So you can use your fan connected to your PC and the mouse speed seems solved too. Nice that it's solved! Do you want to mark my answer as correct? Thanks.